# Can't seem to find Opus engine even tough I have installed opusscript / @discordjs/opus

Tags: javascript, mp3, npm-install, discord.js, opus

I can't install node-opus because it gives error code.

My code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.login('my token :)');
client.on('message', message => {
  if (!message.guild) return;
  if (message.content === '/join') {
    if (message.member.voiceChannel) {
      message.member.voiceChannel.join()
      .then(connection => {
        const dispatcher = connection.playFile('./musik/taisonin.mp3');
        dispatcher.resume()
        dispatcher.on("end", end => {message.memver.voiceChannel.leave()});
      });
    } else {
      message.reply('-');
    }
  }
});
```

everything seems to work fine until it tries to start playing my mp3 file. -> " Error: Couldn't find an Opus engine."

Depencies:

```
"@discordjs/opus": "^0.1.0",
"discord.js": "github:discordjs/discord.js#master",
"discord.js-commando": "github:discordjs/Commando",
"ffmpeg-static": "^4.0.1",
"opusscript": "0.0.7"
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that they have many overlapping functions, you might be receiving an error for trying to install node-opus on top of opusscript.

to decode and encode the mp3 file you want to play you must install a codec to do that for you:

So try uninstalling opusscript then install `npm install discord.js node-opus` and you should be fine.